# timevarying effects in regression vs state space models

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, state-space-models

Consider the following regression model:

$z_t = \alpha + trend_t + seasonality_t + \epsilon$

$\alpha \sim HalfNormal(1)$,

$trend_t = \mu t$ where as $\mu \sim Normal(0, 1)$

$seasonality_t = \sum_k^K [\nu_k S_k(t) + \lambda_k C_k(t)]$

$\nu_k \sim Normal(0, 1), \lambda_k \sim Normal(0, 1)$

where as $S_k(t) = sin(\frac{2\pi kt}{7})$ and $C_k(t) = cos(\frac{2\pi kt}{7})$

That can be estimated with MCMC sampling which also allows us to incorporate nonlinear parameters if we want to.

Why would one want to use a state space formulation of an process instead of adding time-varying effects like above in a model?

I see some negatives, it makes it much harder to incorporate nonlinear parameters, we need particle filters..

The positive i see is that the parameters are allowed to vary over time, even if they do this in this case aswell they are not stochastically evolving over time, i assume if we would try to do this with the above approach we would have far more parameters.. is this the sole reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts on this:

- I wouldn't describe any of the effects in this regression model as time-varying. As you correctly point out in the last paragraph, this is a deterministic seasonal pattern, consisting of a linear trend plus trigonometric components.
- Are the priors on the model coefficients $\alpha, \mu, \{ \nu_k \}, \{ \lambda_k \}$ essential? Given enough observations, you could just estimate them with OLS.

I agree that a state-space model would give you more flexibility. Allowing time-varying coefficients is one advantage, but there are others:

- Your starting point would be a linear state-space model, so you don't need particle filters. You can implement this very easily (and efficiently) with the Kalman filter.
- Even if you assume that your model coefficients are fixed, the Kalman filter would give you estimates of these coefficients at each time point using only the data that has already been observed. This is particularly useful if you're interested in 1-step-ahead forecasts.

Comment: As for the last bulletpoint, lets say i am interested in longer forecasts such as 30-steps, would this change this scenario. Secondly, if i assume the model coefficients are fixed, isnt it strange to then model them stochastically thus allowing for changes w.r.t time? just clarify this and i accept and upvote. thanks

Comment: Suppose that $\mu \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$, as in your model. This is a static parameter, so we have $\mu_t=\mu$ for all $t$. The Kalman filter will give you the estimate $\hat{\mu}_t = \mathbb{E}(\mu|z_1, \ldots, z_{t-1})$ at every time point. In other words, the coefficient itself does not change, but our _estimate_ of it changes as we observe more data.

Comment: The KF will give you the 1-step-ahead forecast by default, but it's straightforward to forecast more steps into the future with this sort of linear model.

Comment: but isnt this the same as in a normal regression context given that we recompute the estimates every timestep -> now this obviously decrease the computational efficiency drastically.